# Excel Formula for counting words with same starting letters

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

Suppose I have a column of words, in some cases more than 1 word in each cell, separated by a comma or space. I want to calculate the number of words starting with A, B, C...,Z separately.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(FLATTEN(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A10; ", "); "^."))); 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(UPPER(FLATTEN(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A10, ", "), "^.")))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]